# How can one remove a range of lines for every group of n lines?

Tags: awk, sed, cat

I want to start with a file that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Return only the last three of every group of five like so:

```
3
4
5
3
4
5
3
4
5
```

I've managed to get the first 2 using a code like this:

```
awk -vn=2 -vm=5 'NR<=i{next}; (NR-i)%m==1{c=1}; c++<=n
```

but I'm having trouble doing the same for the last grouping.

Answer (score 2):

These things are often easier using modulo arithmetic e.g.

```
awk '(NR-2)%5 && (NR-1)%5' file
3
4
5
3
4
5
3
4
5
```

Alternatively, using GNU sed's `n~m` ("n skip m") notation:

```
sed '1~5d;2~5d' file
```

Comment: or `awk '(NR-1)%5>1'` ...

Comment: Another way `sed '1~5{N;d}'`.